# Programming language to compliment Finance degree

Tags: programming, finance

I've read a few questions regarding this, but want some new (more recent) opinions.

I'm in the process of pursuing a degree in Finance, complimented with some Math and a sprinkle of Computer Systems. I recently took a Java class which I had more than a knack for, and decided I wanted to make computer programming a heavier part of my education, with a lean towards financial application. I'm also hoping that having some real skills will help me stand out if the finance sector starts downsizing, as some predict it will.

I am considering learning the C++ language, but am not sure if it would be more useful to learn C++ or to go into something such as Python, R or VBA since I've already learned Java. More importantly is the order that I learn these in. I graduate in two years and am wondering if it would be better to market myself as having fundamental computer skills (like C++) or something that is already targeted, like the previously mentioned languages.

Any other insights would be highly valued as well!

Comment: We can't answer this as it's too subjective. I recommend talking to people you know in the industry, alumni or your university's career counsel.

Comment: Of course it's subjective, I was asking for opinions...

Comment: That type of question is generally not allowed.